# .NET Core 3.1 - cookies not set on redirect unless page is refreshed

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, refresh

We use a third party site for authentication

*Our site (angular) -> 3rd party login prompt -> our site(.NET)*

When they send us the auth code, they address our web service in return

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("authorize")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize(some code)
{
   // we call a web service to get an access token and an expiration time with the provided code
   ...

   // storing cookie since web site needs the token to use our api
   CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
   option.Secure = true;
   option.HttpOnly = false;
   option.Expires = data.expires; // 3600
   Response.Cookies.Append(key, data.access_token, option);
                       
   return Redirect("https://ourwebsite/authorized"); 
}
```

problem: **I always have to refresh the page once this is done**

**the stored cookie is the previous value until I F5 the browser**

what am I missing ?

thanks for your help

Comment: I test redirecting with cookie in my own project,and it can work, do you have any error message?

Comment: non, nothing...it's quiet weird that the cookie ends up with the correct value, but I have to reload the page